# Getting external IP using Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, network-programming, air

We can get external IP [from this service](http://www.whatismyip.com/) using Java, C# or VB.NET. But I want to do that using Adobe AIR. How to make request to that link and get its string?

Comment: Here is a way to get external ip using java or C# from whatismyip.com http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543738/difference-between-internal-ip-address-and-external-ip-address

Comment: The [original link](http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp) in this question was removed as it was broken. I will leave it in place in the answer, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be like this:

```
private function makeRequest():void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

    configureListeners(loader);
    var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp");

    try

    {   
        var header:URLRequestHeader=new URLRequestHeader("content-type", "text/plain");

        var header2:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");

        req.requestHeaders.push(header);
        req.requestHeaders.push(header2);

        req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        loader.load(req);
    }
    catch (error:Error)
    {
        trace("Unable to load requested document.");
    }
}

private function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void
{
    dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
}

private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    mx.controls.Alert.show("" + loader.data);
}
```