# Obtain IP Direction using JAVA

Tags: java, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the 'external' IP address in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java)

i'm using JAVA for a write a simple messenger, but i need know the IP address of the machine where is running my program

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either parse a "what is my IP" website (like http://my-i-p.com/), which usually restrict the frequency you can get the IP.

Or, if you have your own web server, you can have the application contact a PHP page, for example, that prints the IP address on the page. Download that page to retrieve the IP address from the text.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help, but i'm searching the way to obtain the IP address directly using Java

Comment: @Juan: It's not possible without using an external source. See the answer in the "possible duplicate" comment.