# Find out IP address?

Tags: java, android

I've got an app on android, and I'm connecting to a website for some data. Is it possible to find out the IP address that I'm actually connecting to? I'm doing:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

println("You connected to: " + response.getIpAddress(?));
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322506/how-to-get-external-ip-succesfully

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it using the [InetAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) class:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(new URL("http://www.example.com").getHost());
String ipAddress = addr.getHostAddress();
```

Comment: If the destination routes me to another server though, is there any way to find out which ips I hit? For example, hitting google.com will likely route me somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

just use this:
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("http://www.example.com");