# Trouble getting IP of client in ServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, servlets, ip

I'm trying to get remote IP using this:

```
String remoteAddress = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                .currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
```

I call it in controller, but it returns `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1`. What's wrong?

Comment: Are you accessing the Web App from a local (host) browser?

Comment: Is your servlet container fronted by a reverse proxy (like Nginx or Apache Web Server)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` is the loopback adress in IPv6.
It's the equivalent of `127.0.0.1` in IPv4.

If you are using only one machine, this seems pretty normal to me. Otherwise, could you please give more details ?

EDIT

If you are trying to get your external (public) IP, then you could have a look at these SO posts :

[Get real client IP in a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163874/get-real-client-ip-in-a-servlet)

[Getting the 'external' IP address in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java)

[How to get external IP successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322506/how-to-get-external-ip-succesfully)

[Getting the IP address of the current machine using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/how-to-get-ip-address-of-our-own-system-using-java)

In short, you can use `request.getRemoteAddr()`. But it won't return your public IP adress if you are on the same network.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Elaborate as to why he gets this result, or place it as a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm pretty new to this (and just discovered that I can comment not). I've asked the OP for more details.

Comment: What kind of details?

Comment: Like, what is the expected result? You were expecting a different IP adress ? One from another machine ? (Maybe I just don't get your question though)