# My Server sees my router's IP instead of client's

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ip

I have a web-server that is behind a router. One of the servlets on that server relies on the IP address of the user, however, i often get the IP of my router (i.e. 192.168.1.1) instead of the real IP.

How can i fix that?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. Did you find solution?

Comment: No, I had to find a different way out. Unfortunately, I don't remember what exactly I did. Basically, you can identify the user in other ways, like getting their session id, etc.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your "router" is actually acting like a reverse proxy.

It is unlikely that you will be able to solve this in Java ... or even on your server machine.  It sounds like a router configuration problem.  You might be better off asking for help on "superuser" or "serverfault".

One thing to bear in mind is that identifying clients by IP address is always a bit dodgy.  Even once you've sorted out the current problem, the real client IP address may not be available for various reasons:

- The client's IP may be NATed.
- The client may be talking to your webserver via a series of HTTP proxies.
- The client may be spoofing its IP address.

Comment: Yes, but in this case it is guaranteed to be in my lan and controlled by me.

Comment: ... until you change your mind and run the application somewhere else. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Grab your global IP from http://www.whatismyip.com/  , I think you might also need to configure port forwarding on router of user that is having servlet.

Comment: I know my global ip. Basically, i have two computers in my lan. One of them is running a web-server using tomcat+servlets. Another (say, ...32) makes a request to it. I need to be able to tell that IP from my servlet.
Port forwarding also set up

Comment: If the request is local, then there is no need of port forwarding, can you please share that servlet code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that access http://wwww.whatismyip.com to get you IP  adddress in case you have not tried that way.You will more idea from this link.

[Getting the 'external' IP address in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java)