# why the two IP differ?

Tags: java, ip

The following snippet :

```
<%= InetAddress.getLocalHost() %>
```

gives out this : *Feddy/192.168.42.194*

but when I check the website [ipchicken](http://www.ipchicken.com) , I get this :*106.193.214.75*

Why the two IP differ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`106.193.214.75` is a public IP address of your network.

`192.168.42.194` is your local IP address - IP of the machine in internal network. Every machine in your network have the same public IP address.

Answer (score 3):

An address 192.168.x.x is for private internal networks only.  The fact you can talk to the internet means you also have a public IP address.

Its the job of your router to do network address translation so that your devices on your private network all appear with your public address.

Answer (score 2):

The server is behind [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) which gives it a separate IP address locally compared to the one used on public Internet.

There are several reasons why NAT is used, including security and the limitation of available public IPv4 addresses.

Answer (score 1):

192.168.xx.xx is your local ip on your network. 106.193.xxx is your external IP.

You can get both with the following code:

```
        String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();

        InetAddress[] addresses = InetAddress.getAllByName(hostName);
         for (InetAddress a: addresses) {
             System.out.println(a.getHostAddress());
         }
```

Comment: I get address like : 192.168.42.250 fe80:0:0:0:4c6e:3fff:fe24:75a0%16

Comment: the first one is the local IP address and the second one the 'public' ? How to translate it to numeric notation ?

Comment: @Y.E.P That's an IP v6 whereas you seem to want an IP v4 - You can't really translate from one to the other. [Here is an alternative solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

One is your local IP address (from your router) and the other one is your IP address over Internet.

192.168 is always from a router

Comment: rooter, router, roster, always the same ;)

Answer (score 0):

The ip 192.168.42.194 is your local ip, it is given to your pc by your router.

The other ip is your WAN ip, it is given by your isp and is the ip address your router gets for connections from the outside world

Answer (score 0):

Because `192.168.42.194` is your private ip, on your private network, and `106.193.214.75` your public one, assigned to your gateway by your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

In JDK 1.6

```
List<InetAddress> addrs = new ArrayList<InetAddress>();
for(NetworkInterface ni : NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()) {
   if(ni.isUp()) {
      for(InetAddress addr : ni.getInetAddresses()) {
        addrs.add(addr);
      }
   }
}
```

Regards,

Comment: I get address like : `192.168.42.250
fe80:0:0:0:4c6e:3fff:fe24:75a0%16`

Comment: the first one is the local IP address and the second one the 'public' ? How to translate it to numeric notation ?

Comment: In this case you only have one IP V4 (192.168.42.250) and one IP V6 (fe80:0:0:0:4c6e:3fff:fe24:75a0%16), it is the same input with the old version and the new

Comment: If you do not get no more ip means you have a router on the network this redirects you ip to public ip of your network, the public IP is configured on the router