# How to get IP address in windows machine using java

Tags: java

I use this code to get my current IP:

```
public String getIpAddress() throws NullPointerException,
        MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                whatismyip.openStream()));
        String ip = in.readLine();
        return ip;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

but the return value is incorrect. how to get the IP properly

Comment: **How** doesn't it work? Does it explode?

Comment: What do you call your "current IP" anyway? It is a vague notion. `ip addr` will show all my IP addresses on my system.

Comment: I'm not a Java programmer, but this does not look like "getting the IP" at all. You are reading web site contents from a URL. So what do you actually want? If you indeed want the current IP use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/how-to-get-ip-address-of-current-machine-using-java

Comment: i can't post more quetions on this site by above question please.. i am poor in english.. here after  i post clear question. please remove the badges for this question.. i don't know how to improve this question...pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Will's code** on this Thread : [Getting the 'external' IP address in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java#14541376)

He use Amazon service to get his "external IP".

Here his code :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class IpChecker {

    public static String getIp() throws Exception {
        URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    whatismyip.openStream()));
            String ip = in.readLine();
            return ip;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**All credits goes to Will.**

Comment: can you help to get my location by this ip....?

Comment: Android or pure java?
Please ask only one question by Thread, open an other Thread for an other question.