# IP Address: using program or script

Tags: ip

A) The below statement

```
System.out.println(java.net.Inet4Address.getLocalHost());
```

shows output as myhostname/192.168.1.25

B) The http://whatismyipaddress.com/ shows below (masked):

14x.7x.2xx.x1x

Using above mentioned technique A (any language or script), how do I get the value 14x.7x.2xx.x1x that above mentioned technique B shows? Or, is it at all possible?

In other words (?), using technique A (as mentioned in original question), how I can I get the same public Ip address of my home router which is shown by technique B? If it is impossible, please explain briefly (two lines at the most) why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this question:[Getting the 'external' IP address in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java)

The computer don't know its final public address as it is not necessary for it to know. Local network IP Address is sufficient for it for the tasks. But if you want to get the public address you have to use an external service as mentions in the answers of the linked question.

Comment: The first answer on the linked question suggests creating your own web service, running elsewhere on the internet. The second answer refers to an Amazon Web Service which will provide your external IP Address.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are at your home and you have a router for connecting your several computers to the internet.

http://whatismyipaddress.com/ will show an IP address as it is visible on the global internet. This may well be the IP address of your in-home router, which exposes one address for your entire in-home network. This is your public IP address.

The script that you show will give you the IP address of your own machine, which is usually only useful on your own local network. This is a private IP address, only accessible from your local network.

Comment: Okay. Using technique A (as mentioned in original question), how I can I get the same public Ip address of my home router which is shown by technique B?

Comment: You cannot get the public IP address from the OS query. The router translates the IP address at the packet level do the OS does not need to know. If your program needs to pass out the IP, then you can pay your ISP to get a static IP address, and provide that as a constant. Better yet, get a static IP and a domain name, and pass around the domain name.