# Finding my router IP address

Tags: java, routes, ip

Iam just trying to find my router's ip address programmatically in java. When i went through internet i found an url http://ipecho.net/plain which returns ip address of my router in a webpage. Is there a way to bring the content of that webpage to a file in java so that I can use that in my java program. 
Regards

Comment: Obvious question: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to access my modem from another remote device. If the device gets a new ip during a reset, i want to know that.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java, you can use it for http://ipecho.net/plain also

Comment: That link was useful.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You could crawl your own ip. Try:http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-using-java/.