# Get IP address from server in the cloud

Tags: web-services, jsp, ip

I deploy a web service in cloud foundry provider. I include a JSP file to show me the IP address of the server by using:

> inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

I got this response:

> 6dlne5n0dnv/10.254.0.42

However, I cannot `ping 10.254.0.42` this address. So, I cannot access to my web service through this address. How can I obtain the "public" address please ?

Comment: You are not able to ping to 10.254.0.42 coz it is in private IP range.

Comment: @BhushanPatil Ok, How can i obtain the public IP ?

Comment: That will be tricky. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java#answer-2939223

Comment: I got it and it's very simple to obtain it following the like that you given to me. Thank you :)