# Private IP address public through laptop?

Tags: java, networking, mobile

Complete novice with this topic - struggled to grasp an understanding.

Two devices - Device A, Device B(Laptop)

Device A - IP Address 192.169.0.120
Device B - IP address 192.169.0.121

Device B(Laptop) is connected to WiFi, and to Device A through Ethernet cable.

I have an embedded app in Device A, which i access though web browser on Device B(Laptop), on Device A's IP Address.

Is it possible to make this IP address public - for instance my mobile to pick up Device A's IP address?

I've looked into VPN's (hamachi) and port forwarding. is this the right way to go?

[image of example setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfKCV.png)

Comment: Port forwarding would have to be done in the router. So you wouldn't need the laptop if you can connect Device A directly to the local network (router). But even then there can be obstacles: If your provider gives you a DualStack you're out of luck because even your router wouldn't have an exclusive public IPv4. You'd have to resort to IPv6 then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **ngrok** to obtain the public ip address. This will basically expose your machine as public although it is in private network.

reference : https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect from outside the network using your local ip (192.168.0.120). Check out this topic if you want to know how to grab your external ip:

[Getting the 'external' IP address in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java)