# Get IP address of computer in tether mode

Tags: java, android

Is there a programmatic way for an Android device to check the IP address of the computer to which it is connected to while the phone is in tether mode?
Also, the WiFi and data have to be turned off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're checking the public IP address of your computer, then you'll need to ask an outside server: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2939223/2201238

If you're looking for the local IP address of the computer with respect to the tethered network, you'll need to find the gateway IP of that network. It's possible to do this by finding the system property `dhcp.interface_name_here.gateway`. Where you'd replace `interface_name_here` with another value, like `wlan0` (wifi), `rmnet[012345]` (cell or usb tethering), `p2p` (wifi direct), or if you're using HoRNDIS `rndis0`.

```
@Nullable
public String getTetheredGatewayIp() {
    NetworkInterface tetheredNic = getTetheredNetworkInterface();
    try {
        Class<?> systemPropertiesClass = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
        return (String) systemPropertiesClass
                .getMethod("get", String.class)
                .invoke(systemPropertiesClass, "dhcp." + tetheredNic.getName() + ".gateway");
    } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    return null;
}

// Find the NetworkInterface of any 'rndis' NIC:
@Nullable
private NetworkInterface getTetheredNetworkInterface() {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    while (networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface nic = networkInterfaces.nextElement();
        if (nic.isUp() && !nic.isLoopback() && nic.getName().contains("rndis")) {
            return nic;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What is `SystemProperties`, its not found in android. I am trying to do USB tethering.

Comment: Ah, the SystemProperties class has the @hide javadoc. I've updated the code to use reflection. You can also execute the "getprop" process and read the output from it's stream.

Comment: Does not work just returns an empty string. Tested it for both `rndis` and `rmnet`.