# Java socket: Get clients external IP

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, external

I've built a client server application. How can I get the client IP on the serverside? I already used `"socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()"` 
but this gives an internal IP.

Comment: As in the public id? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java#2939223 has a solution for that.

Comment: Thank you two. I found out that it wasn't working because of the firewall configuration, the code itself was good. Problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start to listen with `serverSocket.accept();` and you store the Socket returning object of this function, you can get the client ip with this function from the socket with this: `socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();`.

Comment: Thank you! I found out that it wasn't working because of the firewall configuration, the code itself was good. Problem is solved :)