# How to get public ip of my project in heroku?

Tags: java, heroku

I have a web service in heroku that I need to connect to a database in google sql cloud, google sql cloud needs the public ip of the web service to give it connection authorization. for this I need the public ip of my web service.

Comment: The easiest way is to check with a third party. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java