Thread[#39,PostgreSQL-JDBC-Cleaner,5,server.Server] was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least 15000msecs
I'm trying to run the server of an application, but when i run it from maven they run for like 30 second or so, and then the server shout down and give me this error:
[WARNING] thread Thread[#39,PostgreSQL-JDBC-Cleaner,5,server.Server] was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least 15000msecs [WARNING] thread Thread[#39,PostgreSQL-JDBC-Cleaner,5,server.Server] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption [WARNING] NOTE: 1 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
But if i run the jar the server it doesn't stop until I turn it off.
The problem is that when i try to connect the client side, as long as the server is on I can use the methods to run queries on the postgres database, but when the server shuts down when I try to call the methods it returns error because the server has shut down, this only happens when I start the server from maven, but when I start it from cmd this does not happen and I can run the methods normally.
The main class is the server:

public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements GenericRemoteInterface{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 10L;

    /**
     * The database object.
     */
    private DBAdapterDatabase db;

    /**
     * The port number for the server.
     */
    private final static int PORT=2020; //! DO NOT CHANGE

    /**
     * The constructor of the server.
     * @param port
     * @param db
     * @throws IOException
     */
    protected Server(int port, DBAdapterDatabase db) throws IOException {
        super(port);
        this.db=db;
    }

    /**
     * The main method of the server.
     * @param args not used in this application
     * @throws RemoteException
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, IllegalArgumentException {
        try {
            // Read the arguments
            CliParser.parseCli(args);

            //--- To set the hostname of the server (needed for RMI)
            String ip = null;
            if(!CliParser.isLocal()) { //If it's not local, use the external IP
                // Code thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java
                URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        whatismyip.openStream()));
                ip = in.readLine();
                if(ip==null || ip.isEmpty()){
                    logError("IP not found, exiting...");
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
                System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", ip);
                logInitialMessage("Application starting on external IP: " + ip + "...");
            }else{
                logInitialMessage("Application starting on internal IP...");
            }
            //---

            // Show environment variables on startup
            logEnvironmentVariables();

            DBAdapterDatabase db=new DBAdapterDatabase();
            try {
                db.init();
            }catch (SQLException e){
                logError("DATABASE ERROR: "+e.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            log("---------------------------------------------------");
            log("                       SERVER (V."+serialVersionUID+")                       ");
            log("---------------------------------------------------");

            // To set up the database pool
            ConnectionInstance.setUpDBPool();

            // To create the server
            Server server = new Server(PORT, null);

            // To start the registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(PORT);
            if(CliParser.isLocal())
                log("RMI registry running on port: " + PORT + " on the local host");
            else
                log("RMI registry running on port: " + PORT + " with IP: " + ip);

            registry.bind("server",  server);

       

    }

    /**
     * The method to get the connection.
     * @param userID
     * @param pass
     * @return
     * @throws RemoteException
     */
    public ConnectionInstanceInterface getConnection(String userID, String pass) throws RemoteException {
        User user1=new User();
        //ricerca da db
        return new ConnectionInstance(user1);
    }

    /**
     * The method to get the connection.
     * @return
     * @throws RemoteException
     */
    public ConnectionInstanceInterface getConnection() throws RemoteException {
        return new ConnectionInstance();
    }

    /**
     * Utility method to log environment variables on startup.
     * @throws UnknownHostException
     */
    private static void logEnvironmentVariables() throws UnknownHostException {
        log("------------------ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES--------------------");
        log("POSTGRES_ADMIN_USER: "+ CliParser.getAdminUser());
        log("POSTGRES_ADMIN_PASSWORD: " + CliParser.getAdminPassword());
        InetAddress sqlAddress= InetAddress.getByName(CliParser.getPostgresURL());
        String address = sqlAddress.getHostAddress().replace("/", "");
        log("POSTGRES_URL: "+ CliParser.getPostgresURL() + " WITH IP: " + address);
        log("SERVER_VERSION: " + serialVersionUID);
        log("POSTGRES_MAX_CONNECTIONS: " + CliParser.getMaxConnections() + "  [1020]");
        log("POSTGRES_SHARED_BUFFER: " + CliParser.getSharedBufferSize() + "  [128MB]");
        log("SERVER_MAX_DB_CONNECTIONS: " + CliParser.getMaxDBConnections() + "  [1000]");
        log("----------------------------------------------------------");
    }

}

The complete output when running with maven is:
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< railwai.Server:Server >------------------------
[INFO] Building Server 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ Server ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource from src\main\resources to target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ Server ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec:3.1.0:java (default-cli) @ Server ---


[INFO] server.Server.logEnvironmentVariables:  ------------------ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES-------------------- 
[INFO] server.Server.logEnvironmentVariables:  POSTGRES_URL: localhost WITH IP: 127.0.0.1 
[INFO] server.Server.logEnvironmentVariables:  SERVER_VERSION: 10 
[INFO] server.Server.logEnvironmentVariables:  POSTGRES_MAX_CONNECTIONS: 115  [1020] 
[INFO] server.Server.logEnvironmentVariables:  POSTGRES_SHARED_BUFFER: 128MB  [128MB] 
[INFO] server.Server.logEnvironmentVariables:  SERVER_MAX_DB_CONNECTIONS: 5  [1000] 
[INFO] server.Server.logEnvironmentVariables:  ---------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] database.DBAdapterDatabase.init:  --------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] database.DBAdapterDatabase.init:                        DATABASE                      
[INFO] database.DBAdapterDatabase.init:  --------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] database.DBAdapterDatabase.init:  Integrity check of the database 
[INFO] database.DBAdapterDatabase.init:  The database has already been initialized, proceed to start up the server 
[INFO] database.DBAdapterDatabase.init:  random generato 
[INFO] database.DBAdapterDatabase.init:  Performing database cache (Expect poor performance for the first few minutes) 
[INFO] server.Server.main:  --------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] database.DBAdapterDatabase.lambda$init$0:  Caching the database 
[INFO] server.Server.main:                         SERVER (V.10)                        
[INFO] server.Server.main:  --------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] database.DBAdapterDatabase.cacheDatabase: Database cached successfully
[INFO] server.DBPool$1.run:  Creating DB connections in background. 
[INFO] server.DBPool$1.run:  DB connections created. The server is ready to accept connections. 
[WARNING] thread Thread[#39,PostgreSQL-JDBC-Cleaner,5,server.Server] was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least 15000msecs
[WARNING] thread Thread[#39,PostgreSQL-JDBC-Cleaner,5,server.Server] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] NOTE: 1 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20.072 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-06-30T14:25:26+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0

While the pom file is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>railwai.Server</groupId>
    <artifactId>Server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
        <javaTarget.version>21</javaTarget.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <!-- Compiling plugins -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation=
                                                     "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>server.Server</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${javaTarget.version}</release>
                    <source>${javaTarget.version}</source>
                    <target>${javaTarget.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- javadoc plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

And the command used when I run it is:
compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=server.Server

Whit this environment variables:

POSTGRES_ADMIN_USER=postgres;POSTGRES_URL=localhost;POSTGRES_MAX_CONNECTIONS=115;SERVER_MAX_DB_CONNECTIONS=5;POSTGRES_SHARED_BUFFER=128MB

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?
Thanks in advance to everyone
